# Somewhat advanced MySQL querying (to me at least)

Tags: mysql, sql

Part of my database:

[image]

One device can trigger several actions and the same action can be triggered by different devices, hence the junction table

I want to SELECT all **devices** belonging to a **group** & the **actions** they are linked to (if they happen to be)

I've gotten pretty close using 2 queries one after the other. Problem is, it doesn't return more than one action per device. My clunky workaround also totally separates actionless devices and those that do trigger actions.

```
SELECT 
    d.sigfox_id, type 
FROM 
    groups g, devices d, triggers t, actions a 
WHERE 
    t.action_id = a.action_id 
    AND t.sigfox_id = d.sigfox_id 
    AND d.group_id = g.group_id 
    AND g.name = ? 
GROUP BY 
    t.sigfox_id


SELECT 
    action_id, type 
FROM  
    actions 
WHERE 
    group_id = ?
```

Comment: No idea what you're trying to do, but you should be using a JOIN of some sort.

Comment: Is it mysql or sql-server because they're slightly different (but it won't change this case :)

Comment: it's mysql sorry for the misleading tag

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Great! you get to learn about joins!

```
SELECT 
d.sigfox_id, d.type
action_id
FROM groups g
    LEFT OUTER JOIN actions a ON d.type = g.type
WHERE t.action_id = a.action_id 
AND t.sigfox_id = d.sigfox_id 
AND d.group_id = g.group_id 
AND g.name = ? 
GROUP BY t.sigfox_id
```

Answer (score 1):

looking to your schema you should use a set of inner join  and a distincy clause for avoid duplicated  rew

```
  select distinct a.action_id, a.type 
  from group g 
  inner join  devices d on g.group_id = d.g.group_id  and g.name = ?
  inner join  triggers t on t.sigfox_id = d.sigfox_id 
  inner join actions a on a.action_id = t.action_id
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are grouping with sigfox_id it will give distinct sigfox_id.

execute the query without `GROUP BY t.sigfox_id`

```
SELECT d.sigfox_id, type FROM groups g, devices d, triggers t, actions 
WHERE t.action_id = a.action_id 
AND t.sigfox_id = d.sigfox_id 
AND d.group_id = g.group_id 
AND g.name = ?
```